# file are saving out of the folder, how to save within

Tags: file, lua, coronasdk, luafilesystem

I want to save my files within a folder but the issue which raising is that my files are storing outside of the folder which is annoying. I am sharing what I have done so far.

```
-- get raw path to app's Temporary directory
local doc_path = system.pathForFile( "", system.DocumentsDirectory )

-- change current working directory
local success = lfs.chdir( doc_path ) -- returns true on success
local new_folder_path

if success then
lfs.mkdir( "MyNewFolder" )
new_folder_path = lfs.currentdir() .. "/MyNewFolder"
end

local filePath = system.pathForFile( dataFileName , new_folder_path )
r = media.newRecording(filePath)
--print("new recording has been started with a name"..dataFileName)
r:startRecording()
```

but my recorded file is out of this newly created folder
can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched out and finally got the answer that the problem.This is how to create  a new recording in specified folder

```
r = media.newRecording( new_folder_path.."/"..dataFileName )
```

This line would automatically create a file in this folder as mentioned in the question.
`system.pathForFile()` only creates a file automatically when the second argument is a base directory like `system.DocumentsDirectory` (as it is clearly mentioned in the documentation that the second argument is constant and it should be only any base directory). 
so if you want to create a new file r want to find the path of the file you would append folder name before the file name like `my folder/my file` 
Hope this would help